# add listener to asp.net control using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a checkbook list and text box and drop down list I want to check if the user interact with any of them and they have a value too using j query to apply style on another elements any help ?

Comment: need more details.put some of your codes

Comment: the idea is i need to add event on any of this controls to know if they had a value or not like text box i have this sample of code
 $('#TextBox1').change(function () {
alert($(this).val());
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery like this :

Markup :

```
<asp:textbox ID='text1' runat='server' Text="a value"></asp:textbox>
```

Jquery Code :

```
$("#<%= text1.ClientID %>").live('change',function(){

    if($(this).val() != "")
        //Do Somthing

});
```

for checkbox :

```
$("#<%= checkbox1.ClientID %>").live('click',function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked') != "")
        //Do Somthing

});
```

Comment: what if it was check box list or drop down list i have some thing for text box and it works
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#TextBox1').change(function () {
                var x = $(this).val();
                if (x) {
                    $("#text_Div").addClass('div_Act');
                    $("#text_Div").removeClass('div_org');

                } else {

                    $("#text_Div").removeClass('div_Act');
                    $("#text_Div").addClass('div_org');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
will be usfull if  found some to the rest